# Moshi: multiple JSON properties into one field of a class

Tags: android, json, parsing, kotlin, moshi

Let's say we have this JSON structures:

```
"data": [
        {
            "order_id": 460,
            "order_no": "365"
        },
        ....
]

"data": {
        "id": 460,
        "order_no": "365"
}
```

One is order listing, another is order details. To parse such structures I would like to reuse same class.

```
data class Order (
    @Json(name = "id") val id: Int?,
    @Json(name = "order_id") val orderId: Int?,
    @Json(name = "order_no") val orderNumber: Int
)

data class OrderListingResponse (
    @Json(name = "data") val data: List<Order>
)

data class OrderDetailsResponse (
    @Json(name = "data") val data: Order
)
```

This implementation looks ok until different naming of properties with the same data becoming too many. I would like to merge multiple properties into one so I can make my reusable class shorter and more elegant for order listing and order details:

```
data class Order (
        @Json(names = ["id", "order_id"]) val id: Int,
        @Json(name = "order_no") val orderNumber: Int
    )
```

How to achieve such result using Moshi without creating additional fields in the class and just reuse same field with different naming of properties in JSON?

Appreciate if you can provide sample code for custom annotation implementation. Using interfaces is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom type adapter to get multiple JSON fields into a single property.

**Steps:**

1. Create a custom type adapter which will convert your json fields into the properties. (use your logic of order_id/id).
2. Register the custom type adapter with `Moshi.Builder`

Comment: Very appreciate if you can provide example code. How exactly to implement this.